# How ensure at least one service is running on every Docker Swarm node

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Hi have docker swarm running currently on 3 nodes as managers.  I have a simple service replicated 6 times spread evenly across all 3 nodes.  However when I take 1 or 2 of the nodes offline then all the services spread between the remaining node/nodes.  When I bring all the nodes back online all of the services remain on the node/nodes that were not taken offline.  I know this is by design as the concept is you can't take services offline for the sake of re-balancing. However to run this in production I would need to have at least 1 service running on a node at all times.

Is there anyway to auto-balance to ensure at least one service is running on every Docker Swarm node?

Answer (score 1):

**This wont work for multiple replicas per node**. But incase you are not aware of **global** services:

Swarm mode has two types of services, `replicated` and `global`. For `replicated` services, you specify the number of replica tasks for the swarm manager to schedule onto available nodes. For `global` services, the scheduler **places one task on each available node**.

```
docker service create \
  --name <service name> \
  --mode global \
  <image name:tag>
```

Please note `--mode global`.

The `replicated` mode is the default.

> I know this is by design as the concept is you can't take services
>   offline for the sake of re-balancing

You can scale down and scale up again to rebalance the containers across the nodes without downtime, because one container will be available at all times.

Comment: So I may have worded my question wrongly.  I don't mind if there is more than one service running on each node my requirement is that in a production environment there is always at least 1 service minimum running on each node. As for re-balancing I was hoping there was a more automated way to do it using swarm rather than manually or writing scripts i.e. if a node comes back online swarm works drains the service instance running on one of the active nodes and shifts it to the newly started node

Comment: @SteveFitzsimons Did you found a solution to this issue. I recently experience this problem after aws suffered a network problem that affected 3 servers out of 5. Docker moved services back to the two available hosts. Problem happened after the servers became available again, docker didn't push them back to servers. Had to manually run a docker update to re-balance.

Comment: The option I'm considering is using traefik to expose any external services and then use its weighting flags to drain services before switching to a new one.  Not ideal but the only option I really have as Swarm seems to just kill a container even if there are open connections